# regex with look around to match following

Tags: regex-lookarounds

need to write regex to match quoted and unquoted item

```
\"[a-z,A-Z]+.*\"|\b[a-z,A-Z,0-9]+.*(?<=[\n+\r+\s+]})
```

sample data for matching

```
"visitor block" {
    option {
      disable-server-response no;
    }
    source any;
    category any;
    tag guest-in;
  }
  visitor_Internet {
    option {
      disable-server-response no;
    }
    source-user any;
    action allow;
  }
  "Deny guest" {
    option {
      disable-server-response no;
    }
    action deny;
    tag guest;
  }
```

By regex I need to select string in double quotes (visitor block,Deny guest) and also string not in quotes such that visitor_Internet.only name string to capture

Comment: Regex may not be the best tool here, because you have nested content.  Instead, consider writing some simple parsing logic.

Comment: I have managed to get data such that : 
{
"@name":"Final drop from dmz to outside",
"option":
}  now i am trying to capture "Final drop from dmz to outside" with named capture group of regex.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want

- to capture a substring at the start of a *line*
- that is inside double quotes and starts with an ASCII letter
- and then capture all text from the `{` until the `}` that is followed with line break and any whitespaces followed with the first group pattern, or at the end of string.

You may use

```
(?ms)^\s*"([a-zA-Z][^"]*)"\s*{(.*?)}(?=\h*\n\s*"[a-zA-Z][^"]*"\s*{|\s*\z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R3Pl75/2)

**NOTE**: This won't work if there are non-matching lines between the blocks.

**Details**

- `(?ms)` - multiline and dotall modes on
- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `"` - a `"`
- `([a-zA-Z][^"]*)` - Group 1: an ASCII letter and then 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `{`  - a `{` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `}` - a `}` char that is followed with
- `(?=\h*\n\s*"[a-zA-Z][^"]*"\s*{|\s*\z)` - either

  - `\h*\n\s*"[a-zA-Z][^"]*"\s*{` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces, a newline, 0+ whitespaces, `"`, an ASCII letter, 0+ chars other than `"`, `"` and then 0+ whitespaces and `{`
  - `|` - or
  - `\s*\z` - 0+ whitespaces at the very end of the string.